# How can I retrieve data using SQLite in react native app

Tags: react-native, sqlite

I'm using react native with SQLite, in the console log the table when created but I can't retrieve the data from my `category` table.

Here is my code:

```
    import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite'
    const db = SQLite.openDatabase('mydatabase.db');
    // import {createTableCategory,createCategory} from '../Store/Categories';

    const HomeScreen = () => {

      const navigation = useNavigation();
      const [data, setData] = useState([]);

      const createTable=async()=>{
        await db.transaction(tx => {
          tx.executeSql(
            'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS category (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, logo TEXT, type TEXT);'
          );
          console.log(db._db._name)
          console.log('table created');

        });
        await db.transaction(tx => {
          tx.executeSql(
            'INSERT INTO category (id,name, logo, type) VALUES (?,?,?,?);',
            [1,'name','logo','t'],
            (_, result) => {
              console.log('Insertion successful');
            },
            (_, error) => {
              console.log('Insertion failed', error);
              return true;
            }
          );
        }, error => {
          console.log('Transaction failed', error);
        }, () => {
          console.log('Transaction completed');
        });

        await db.transaction(tx => {
          tx.executeSql(
            'SELECT * FROM category',
            [],
            (_, result) => {
              console.log(result.rows.raw()); 
            },
            (_, error) => {
              console.log('Select failed', error);
              return true;
            }
          );
        });
      }
    
      // CRUD operations on the category table

      useEffect( () => {
        createTable();
        
      }, [db])
```

How can I get data when loading the page? The error log doesn't show anything either, I just get this output at the console:

```
 LOG  mydatabase.db
 LOG  table created
```